# Add items one at a time to a "cart" using checkboxes with Django, Ajax, and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

New code now included, but still not working...

I am trying to use checkboxes to select an item(s) an add it to the "cart" at the top of the page. Every item on the page has a checkbox next to it that, when selected, should add the item to the cart and display that item name in the "cart" section at the top of the page. So, as the user goes down the page and checks an item, I want that item name to appear in the "cart" section at the top of page.

(i.e. check an item and the item name appears at top of page; check another item and that item name appears beside the first item at the top of the page; etc.)

With previous versions of my code, I have been able to get the first item listed on the page (and only the first item) to actually show in the "cart" section. I have tried everything I can, but I am completely new to Django, Ajax, and Jquery. Can someone please help!? Thank you!

"cart" section of list.html:

```
    <div id="programCart">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellpadding ="2" border="2" id="selected_programs_cart">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td id="selectionsHere"> SampleSelection1 </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
```

html that lists the items with a checkbox next to each, part of list.html (these items are displayed with a larger 'for' loop):

```
<td>
<form id="programs-selected" method="GET" action="select_citations">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/citations.js"></script>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="programCheckbox" name="programs_to_add" value="{{software.id}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
</form>
```

selectitems.js:

```
$('#programCheckbox').click(function(){
    var softwareID
    softwareID = $(this).attr("value")

    $.get('add_to_cart', function(data){
        $tbody = $("selected_programs_cart").find('tbody');
        $.each(data, function(){
            var displayCart = json.addingToCart;
            for (var key in displayCart)
                if (key == 'cart'){
                    var value = displayCart[key];
                    for (var softwareName in value)
                        $("<td>" + softwareName + "<td>").appendTo($tbody);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

itemview.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):
#dict of 'cart' to list of selected programs to return
to_JSON = {}

#Programs are already in the cart and the "cart" key already exists in the session-
if 'cart' in request.session:
    logger.warning("cart found")
    software_id = request.GET.get('softwareID')
    softwareObject = Software.objects.get(pk='software_id')
    softwareName = softwareObject.title

    addingToCart = request.session.get('cart')
    request.session['addingToCart'].append(softwareName)

    to_JSON = request.session['addingToCart']

#first time clicking on a program, no existing cart in session: the session should store 'cart' as the key and a list of selected programs as the value
else:
    logger.warning("cart not found")
    #get the softwareID of the most recently clicked program
    software_id = request.GET.get('softwareID')
    if software_id == None:
        #oops, can't retrieve this from the request
        logger.warning("cannot find software_id in the request")
        return HttpResponse(request) # TODO: there's probably a better way to handle this
    else:
        logger.warning( "request.GET.get('softwareID'): {}".format(request.GET.get('softwareID')) )
        try:
            softwareObject = Software.objects.get(pk='software_id')
        except Software.DoesNotExist as e:
            logger.warning("oh oh, Someone is trying to access a Software ID that doesn't exist: {}".format(e))
            # TODO: what to do if this happens?
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.warning("oh dear: {}".format(e) )

            #TODO: if an exception happens, the softwareObject won't exist, what should happen then?
        softwareName = softwareObject.title

        #create an entry in the session dictionary for the cart and program list
        request.session['cart'] = []

        #add the first selected program to the list
        request.session['cart'].append(softwareName)

        addingToCart = request.session['cart']
        to_JSON = request.session['addingToCart']

response_data = json.dumps(to_JSON)
return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')

#return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cart, ensure_ascii=False), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is fairly broad, and will most likely get closed or downvoted out of existence, but I thought I'd try to steer you in the right direction.

Your view function is pretty far from being able to return JSON that your jQuery method can consume and use to update the DOM. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse

# or if you're using Django 1.7, you can use the JsonResponse class:
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

from your_app.models import Software


def add_to_cart(request):
    # get an existing cart from the request
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {'items': []})

    # get the objects for the ids in the request
    software_ids = request.GET.getlist('software_ids')
    software = Software.objects.filter(id__in=software_ids)

    # append the items to the cart
    cart['items'].append(software)

    # set the cart into session so you can persist it across requests
    request.session['cart'] = cart

    # dump the cart to JSON and send back a the response
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cart, ensure_ascii=False),
        content_type='application/json')
```

Something important to keep in mind here is that anything you want to put into session has to be serializeable to a string. The [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/) module is great for encoding/decoding complex Python objects to JSON.

Keeping concerns separate, you might want to pass the data returned from the response to a JavaScript templating function, like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template)'s `_.template()` and pass it the data from the response, rather than return HTML from the view.

There are also pre-made carts for Django: [django-cart](https://github.com/bmentges/django-cart) and [django-carton](https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton). There's also this [comparison chart](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/ecommerce/) of Django e-Commerce packages. Hope that gets you going.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your advice. I've been working on this for days so anything to at least point me in the right direction is great.

Comment: You're welcome. I know how frustrating it can be when you know what you want to do, but are learning a new framework at the same time. Please let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: Hi Brandon- I tried to hold out as long as possible but still haven't been able to get it to work...I posted my new code. Is there one place in particular I'm going wrong? I'm experimenting with a JavaScript templating function like you mentioned as well, but no luck yet. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @steph. I'll try to take a look as soon as possible for you.

Comment: I the easiest way I can demonstrate this is with a sample application, as there are a few issues to address here, which I can come back later and add to an answer. I'll send you a link to a downloadable sample app here in a bit.

Comment: Might be a little while before I can get it to you, but will do so today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Please email me via the website listed on my profile and I'll send you the link to the sample project.